# Ember Js app Cannot find module 'exists-sync'

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an ember app on windows. it was working fine but next time when I open the app and tried to run the ember server it showns below error:-
Cannot find module 'exists-sync'

Require stack:

- C:\Users\sudhegup\workspace\hello-world\node_modules\ember-d3\index.js
- C:\Users\sudhegup\workspace\hello-world\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\package-info-cache\package-info.js
- C:\Users\sudhegup\workspace\hello-world\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\package-info-cache\index.js
- C:\Users\sudhegup\workspace\hello-world\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\project.js
- C:\Users\sudhegup\workspace\hello-world\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\utilities\get-config.js
- C:\Users\sudhegup\workspace\hello-world\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\utilities\instrumentation.js
- C:\Users\sudhegup\workspace\hello-world\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\sudhegup\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\bin\ember

Stack Trace and Error Report: C:\Users\sudhegup\AppData\Local\Temp/error.dump.38e564a950a8c68dec21fb3ab79134d2.log

I should have run successfully as it was running before.

Comment: hello! what version of ember-d3 are you using? did your lockfile change?

Comment: It is 0.5.1. I have removed it from packase.json and ember s is working. Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was resolved by the submitter

Comment: Hi Sudheer and welcome to SO. Could you post your solution as answer please for the benefit of others?